# `setTimeout`, passed through string, returns error

Tags: javascript, html, css

These are two pieces of identical code; but first one works properly:

```
function dismiss(obj) {setTimeout(function() {obj.style.display = "none";}, 20);}
```

while second one returns `error: obj is not defined`:

```
function dismiss(obj) {setTimeout('obj.style.display = "none"', 20);}
```

Why is this so?
P.S.: **[An example](http://jsbin.com/zeworiruwi/11/edit?html,js,console,output)**

Comment: I guess because it doesn't capture the closure and executes in the global scope.

Comment: _Why does this so?_ – because in the first version, the anonymous function creates a closure, therefor preserving a reference to `obj` in the local scope, whereas the second one runs in the scope of the global object.

Comment: Actually both work for me in Firefox 38.0.5

Comment: Please read the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Passing_string_literals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer lies in [closures](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp), [or more in depth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

In the first example, the `obj` variable is captured when the anonymous function is created. When the function is run the captured `obj` reference is used to access `style`, which works fine.

However in the second, there is no closure since the string is run through `eval` *inside* `setTimeout` which as stated on the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Passing_string_literals), will be executed inside the global context:

> String literals are evaluated in the global context, so local symbols in the context where setTimeout() was called will not be available when the string is evaluated as code.

The global context does not contain the `obj` variable, which leads to the *"not defined"* error.

Comment: More detailed explanation of closures: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: @FelixKling, thanks, thought there should be a more detailed explanation somewhere.

Comment: nice. much clearer than my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`obj` only exists in the scope of the `dismiss()` function and everything within it. The first statement defines a function, so it can reference it. The 2nd statement executes outside of that scope and cannot reference it.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout):

`Code executed by setTimeout() is run in a separate execution context to the function from which it was called. As a consequence, the this keyword for the called function will be set to the window (or global) object; it will not be the same as the this value for the function that called setTimeout.`:

In both examples, the scope of the timeout code is the global context, or `window`.

In the first example, the context doesn't matter since `obj.style.display` is not evaluated until the timeout is triggered. At that time, `obj` has whatever value was originally passed to `dismiss`, and everything works fine.

In your second example, the code is executed immediately, where `obj` is undefined in the global `window` scope (or if it's defined, it's not what you expect it to be at this point), so effectively you've generated this code:

```
function dismiss(obj) {setTimeout(function ()  { undefined = "none" }, 20);}
```

Answer (score -6):

The correct code should look like this:

```
function dismiss(obj) {setTimeout(obj.style.display = "none", 20);}
```

Because you add `'` at first and last of `obj.style.display = "none"` so it will become a string.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question and it’s wrong. Statements like those that aren’t wrapped in functions are executed or evaluated immediately.

Comment: Furthermore, this is like passing `'none'` as the first argument. `none` is not a function or not defined, however.